# How can i get all phone numbers from call log to a custom List view in Android?

Tags: android, list, listview, calllog

I want to access all phone numbers from android phone call log to a Custom Listview. Custom ListView already created and working fine with accessing all phone numbers from Phone contacts. Could any body please explain ?

Comment: Just a suggestion you should google before asking on stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes already googled could not find appropriate answer that is why I posted here.

Comment: Not a problem you can check out my answer

Comment: yes I am working with it

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this

     ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                    null, null, null, null);
            if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
                while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                      String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                      String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                      if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(
                            cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                         Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                                   ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                   null,
                                   ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
                                   new String[]{id}, null);
                         while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                             String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                             Toast.makeText(ArticleActivity.this, "Name: " + name + ", Phone No: " + phoneNo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         }
                        pCur.close();
                    }
                }
            }
```